# Print multiple arrays into html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have two arrays built from an XML response to an api. One array gives me the product info form one store and the other array gives me just the stock level in another. It looks like this:

```
foreach($filteredStock as $t=>$k){
    $codeFirst[] = $k['code'];

    echo '<tr><td>'.$t;
    echo '</td><td>'.$k['desc'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$k['family'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$_POST['filterSelect'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$k['onOrder'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$k['cost'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$k['sell'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$k['invStore'];
    echo '</td>';
}

$output = array();

$result = array_intersect_key($mainArray, array_flip($codeFirst));
foreach($result as $results=>$rValues){

    echo '<td>'.$rValues['inv'];
    echo '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I want to display it so that it looks like this in the table:

code / desc / family / filteredClass / onOrder / cost  / sell / invStore  / invwarehouse

Because I need the second `foreach` loop to grab the values of the second array it causes a problem trying to get it to repeat on each line with the other array. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than echoing output each time the loop iterates, why don't you build up the table how you want it and then output it when you have it arranged properly?

It's not clear to me from the code exactly what you are trying to do, but if it's an organisation problem then why don't you store the values in seperate arrays and then combine then and arrange them appropriately before outputting them?

Using echo immediately for each loop iteration limits your options somewhat.

Comment: I feel kinda dumb now. Should have thought about that. So you are saying just add the values from one array to the first then do all the echoing? Sorry about the vagueness, I was not sure if all the info was needed yet.

Comment: Yep - you don't need to echo out from the loop each time it runs. There's no rush! It might be better to run both loops, collect your information, and arrange it properly how you want before you echo it.

Look up implode and explode for different ways of combining and seperating arrays with PHP. Hope that points you in the right direction.